# output a line to a line before in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following case in ruby:

```
f.puts "The result is: "
my_array.flatten.each {|n| f.puts n}    //my_array is constructed before and  it outputs the correct line
```

As you can see I'm writing the string "The result is: " into a file. Now I would like to output the result of my_array on the same line and not a line under.

I tried it with:

```
f.puts "The result is: #{my_array.flatten.each {|n| f.puts n}}"
```

But it's not right. Any idea=

Comment: You might want to use `print` instead of `puts`. `puts` adds a line break to the output, `print` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f.puts "The result is: #{my_array.flatten.join(" ")}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The line you have tried: `f.puts "The result is: #{my_array.flatten.each {|n| f.puts n}}"` is almost correct.

The problem is that when you iterate over the values in the `each` loop, you are just printing them to the file, before the string is fully constructed. What you should do is to just convert the values into a String, and then just `f.puts` that string.

So, instead of `flatten.each {|n| f.puts n}` you could use `flatten.join(', ')`.

Alternatively, you could use `f.print` instead of `puts` - the `print` does not append the newline character, so this code would also work:

```
f.print "The result is: "
my_array.flatten.each {|n| f.print n, " "}
f.puts # or f.print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  `#{}` is taking the return value of the command, which is the array itself. You can do this in one command using `.join`:

```
f.puts "The result is:\n#{my_array.flatten.join("\n")}"
```

It will give the required output.